# File Open/Save Dialog always 'Not Responding'

Tags: windows-vista

I am aware that this question has been asked once, however the solution for them didn't work with me.

Whenever I go to open/save a file in any program, the dialog does not come up, and the application goes to 'Not Responding'. This goes on for about a few minutes, and then stops, but still does not open the dialog.

There have been a few occasions where the dialog has suddenly worked for a while, but then the problem comes back.

I have tried many solutions given around the internet, I have cleaned it with CCleaner, disk defragged it, sorted the index. Nothing works. Is there anybody who has any idea what the problem is?

This is Windows Vista. I'm not quite sure what kind of information you guys would need about my laptop, but I'll give you it if you need it. :)

**Solutions I have Tried:**
I have tried deleting the 'Shellicon' folder in the registry, which wasn't even in there.
I have looked for mapped network drives lingering around, and I haven't come across any.
I have tried rebuilding teh Widnows Search Indexes...no difference.

Comment: What solution didn't work for you? It would be helpful to know this so we aren't regurgitating old answers.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is if there are any lingering mapped drives around in "My Computer". When you open the open/save dialog it queries these drives, so if any are no longer available it will cause this delay waiting for the timeout.

We ran into this issue at my old job when we had a server go down and we rebuilt it with a different hostname. I insisted they use the same hostname or make a CNAME in DNS but nobody listened to me and we had all sorts of users complaining about this "hanging". Some users have drives mapped from our branch offices which are accessed over the MPLS connection... we would see this complaint when MPLS went down too :)

Comment: Hmm...I went to my computer and checked for the 'Network Drives' but there were none, I believe this is the same thing right?
Thanks for your help though! :)

Comment: What about in "My Network Places" ?

Comment: Where can I find that in Vista?

Comment: From an elevated command prompt, type `net use` and it should show all mapped drives, even those that are disconnected. I agree with John that this is related to network.

Comment: Just tried it now, "new connections will be remembered, there are no entries in the list"
Not looking too good!

Comment: Where does your open/save dialog open to by default?

Comment: Oh umm..I'm really sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. How can I found out?

Comment: Open one of the dialogs and tell us what you see when it unfreezes

Comment: It just shows the program, no dialog, just the program as it was before.

Comment: Is this only for specific software or all software? You can try reinstalling the culprit.

Comment: Yeah it happens on all software. :s

Comment: Does this same issue occur when using safe mode? Tap F8 when your computer is booting and select safe mode with the arrow keys.

Comment: Tried it, still crashes.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with Microsoft's DEP "feature". You can turn off DEP for certain applications but it requires you to navigate to the `.exe` files with an open dialog =(

Comment: Arghh! That's so unfortunate. Is there nothing else I can do?

Comment: If you have th Vista disk lying around you can try to check the system files for integrity: `sfc /scannow` . Have you installed anything lately?

Comment: No I don't believe so, I'll try the scan...

Comment: Okay, I scanned it and this came up:
"Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation"